# Maven environment variables on MACOSX

Tags: macos, maven

I have MacOSX 10.8.3.  Maven was installed as part of the Spring STS installation.  I am new to unix/maven etc.  and am trying to understand if I need to set any environment variables or paths.  From the terminal I can type mvn -v and I get a response:

> Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 17:31:09+0000) Maven home:
>   /usr/share/maven Java version: 1.7.0_21, vendor: Oracle Corporation
>   Java home:
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
>   Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8 OS name: "mac os x",
>   version: "10.8.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

But I dont see any path entries, or any M2_HOME variables exported so am not sure how even mvn -v is providing a response (no path to a bin folder?).

echo $PATH gives

> /usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin

and export gives:

> declare -x Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render="/tmp/launch-9lPMFU/Render"
>   declare -x
>   Apple_Ubiquity_Message="/tmp/launch-o1QSkR/Apple_Ubiquity_Message"
>   declare -x COMMAND_MODE="unix2003" declare -x
>   DISPLAY="/tmp/launch-kr0aSv/org.macosforge.xquartz:0" declare -x
>   HOME="/Users/me" declare -x
>   JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/Home"
>   declare -x LANG="en_GB.UTF-8" declare -x LOGNAME="me" declare -x
>   OLDPWD="/Users/me" declare -x
>   PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin"
>   declare -x PWD="/Users/me/Downloads" declare -x SHELL="/bin/bash"
>   declare -x SHLVL="1" declare -x
>   SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/tmp/launch-Jhd7XW/Listeners" declare -x
>   TERM="xterm-256color" declare -x TERM_PROGRAM="Apple_Terminal" declare
>   -x TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION="309" declare -x TERM_SESSION_ID="0B75432B-E0F0-4644-8197-848207C66C8E" declare -x
>   TMPDIR="/var/folders/x5/9gzybc0s3sj_bbt0_b1bts2c0000gn/T/" declare -x
>   USER="me" declare -x __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING="0x1F5:0:0"

I can see there is a symbolic link in use for the installation

in /usr/share

> maven -> java/maven-3.0.3

just trying to understand what is already done, and where its done...and if I have to do anything else?

Regards

i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When maven prints out this output you get anything is ok and you do not need to change anything. And you found the maven home folder /usr/share/maven and the symbolic link for easier updating to newer maven versions.

But on the command line you call mvn. To execute this command it must be part of the $PATH which consist of

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin
```

So to find the missing link execute the following statement on a terminal:

```
which mvn
```

This should show you where the mvn command can be found, which should be also as sym link to /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn or something like this and should be in of the folders located in your PATH variable.

Comment: Hi, thanks. which mvn gives me /usr/bin/mvn which is a symbolic link to /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn.  I have a path entry to usr/bin - so that explains it I think!! Thanks

Comment: Hi, can I check where the M2_HOME environment variables are set up?  I cant see them set when i run an EXPORT command?  Also, just realised I am listing 3.03 of Maven which comes with Mac OSX not 3.04 which comes with STS installation...so need to upgrade Maven somehow.

Comment: When export to not list it its not set. Maven do not require the variable because the mvn commands know were he finds itself and his needed files. To upgrade Maven you can unpack a new version to /usr/share next to the maven-3.0.3 folder you found and correct the symlink to point to maven-3.0.4. Or you have a look at http://www.macports.org/ and install maven via this tool.

Comment: Thanks.  Do I need to install Maven 3.0.4 as Eclipse STS seems to be set to use Maven 3.0.4 (embedded).  Not sure what embedded means, but I assume it is pointing to the 3.0.4 installation that came with its installation - but isnt on any system path.

Comment: Embedded normally means the STS brings his own maven and use this. So STS do not care if you have maven installed or not it uses his own by knowing were to search for it. Sometimes you can override the embedded version used by a env variable (maybe M2_HOME). But I do not know the STS plugin enough.